# replace the the first line of all .sh files in a folder

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Create list of all .sh files in current folder.
Check first line of each file in this list and
if file starts with `#!/bin/sh` then replace that
with `#!/bin/bash`. Only modify files
that have `#!/bin/sh`, do not blindly replace
first line of all .sh files with `#!/bin/bash`.

Also the replacement needs to be done
only to starting sequence.
If file has `#!/bin/sh` somewhere in between
do not replace that. You do not have to search
for .sh recursively in sub-folders,
do replacement only in files in current folder.

Comment: homework again - you're supposed to do it on your own, you know. Use `sed`

Comment: Are you just going through your homework and posting all the questions on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash 

FILES=/home/prashanth/now/*.sh

for f in $FILES

do

   x=$(head -n 1 $f)
   y="#!/bin/sh"
   if [ $x == $y ];
   then
       sed -i.bak '1 s/sh/bash/' $f 
   fi
done
```

Comment: Really this is horrifying.  It should be a one-liner: `for f in *.sh; do [ -f "$f" ] && sed -i '1s,^!#/bin/sh$,!#/bin/bash,' "$f" ; done`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have thousands of ".sh"-files, and no sub-directories ending in ".sh", you could use:

`gawk -i inplace 'NR==1 && $0=="#!/bin/sh" {$0="#!/bin/bash"} 1' *.sh`